How can I force subtables' caption start from (a)?
I am writing my thesis on top of following template where subtables detected as a new table and incremented from 1.1 rather than laballed as (a) and (b). I have no idea what prevents that.
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subfigure} %
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\label{chapter:introduction}

\begin{table}[!htp]
    \caption{Average ...}~\label{tab:mytable}
    \begin{subtable}% {1\linewidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
          \hline
          \textbf{Method}            & \textbf{Gas Used} & \textbf{Ethereum} & \textbf{Polygon}  \\
                                     & \textbf{(gas)}    & \textbf{USD cost} & \textbf{USD cost} \\
          \hline
          submitJob                  & 264967            & 7.04              & 0.019             \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Obtained from A environment.}

        \vspace{0.5cm}

        \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|}
          \hline
          \textbf{Method}              & \textbf{Gas Used} & \textbf{Ethereum} & \textbf{Polygon}  \\
                                       & \textbf{(gas)}    & \textbf{USD cost} & \textbf{USD cost} \\
          \hline
          updateProviderInfo           & 33284             & 0.88              & 0.002             \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Obtained from B platform.}
    \end{subtable}%
\end{table}
\end{document}

Output:

Wanted output:


Your code gives errors, the first one being the most important: ! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation with the subfigure package. So remove \usepackage{subfigure} which you have two times, remove both of them. Then there is another error: ! Missing number, treated as zero. because you have {1\linewidth} in comments. Add that back in and it will show (a) and (b) as desired.

First of your probably should not use both subfigure (which is loaded twice) and subcaption in the same document.  I would go with the latter as the former is marked obsolete.

@Marijn strange I don't get that error on TL24.

@daleif I use TL2022, maybe subcaption got updated in between to be less strict. Anyway, hopefully the solution (removing the other package and providing a width) still works in newer versions.

I am dependent on using \usepackage{subfigure} for other figures I have :-(

Probably subcaption can also do what you currently use subfigure for, you could ask another question (or search for existing questions) on how to modify your code to use the newer package.

The subfigure package has been deprecated for close to 20 years. Don't use it. Instead, use just the subcaption package.

Ah when I remove it I started to get ! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode. error for all the figures I have, will be asked as a new question

To quote from the CTAN page of the subfigure package:

The [subfigure] package is now considered obsolete: it was superseded by subfig, but users may find the more recent subcaption package more satisfactory.

In short: Don't use the subfigure package.
The following solution employs the subcaption package. Note that this package's subtable and subfigure environments take one, mandatory argument: the intended width. For the use case at hand, I suggest you use \textwidth (or, equivalently, \linewidth) as the intended width.

\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}   % for 'w' column type and '\extrarowheight' length parameter
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0.333\baselineskip}

% handy utility macro:
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\smash{%
   \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}

\newlength\mylen

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}


\begin{table}[!htp]
\settowidth\mylen{updateProviderInfo} % calculate target width of first column
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look

\caption{Average ...} \label{tab:mytable}
 
\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|wl{\mylen}|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 Method & \mytab{Gas Used\\(gas)} 
        & \mytab{Ethereum\\USD cost} 
        & \mytab{Polygon\\USD cost} \\
 & & & \\ \hline
 submitJob & 264967 & 7.04 & 0.019 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
 
\medskip
\caption{Obtained from A environment.}
\end{subtable}

\bigskip

\begin{subtable}{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|wl{\mylen}|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 Method & \mytab{Gas Used\\(gas)} 
        & \mytab{Ethereum\\USD cost} 
        & \mytab{Polygon\\USD cost} \\
 & & & \\ \hline
 updateProviderInfo & 33284 & 0.88 & 0.002 \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 
\medskip
\caption{Obtained from B platform.}
\end{subtable}
 
\end{table}
\end{document}

